# onClick function not creating option in select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
    function getOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    if(select.options.length > 0) {
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        alert("Text: " + option.text + "\nValue: " + option.value);
    } else {
        window.alert("Select box is empty");
    }
}

function addOption(){
    var select = document.getElementById("dynamic-select");
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('New Element', '0', false, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .pac-container {
            z-index: 10000 !important;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Shipping Method</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Deliver To *</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select id="dynamic-select">
                            <option value="None">Select Shipping</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Delivery Address</a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>Add your Delivery Details</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                          <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                         <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
                                            onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
                                            <br>
                                         <div id="address">
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="street_number">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="route">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">City</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control field" id="locality">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                                  <label class="control-label">State</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="postal_code">
                                               </div>
                                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                                                  <input class="form-control" id="country">
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <button type="submit" onclick="addOption()">Add NEW</button>
                                      </div>
                                        </div>            
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to Javascript and in this example, basically I have created a Shipping Method Page. In the "ADD Delivery Address" link, on clicking there is a address form which needs to be filled out and after pressing the ADD NEW button, all the address form data should appear in the select menu option like in the picture below. But I'm unable to do so. Can someone please enlighten me on his. It would be a immense help to me. Thank you

[image]

Comment: You have no element with an id `"newopt"`, so `$('#newopt').val();` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

This is line bug, id newopt don't exist in html.

```
var newopt = $('#newopt').val();
```